# dvwa is prompting me to check config file when trying to create database

Tags: configuration, dvwa

I believe I have made the proper changes to the `xampp/htdocs/DVWA-1.9/config/config.inc.php` file and the `xampp/passwords.txt` file. The passwords match, security is low, port is changed (not sure if I did that correctly) but it's still telling me to check the config file. I have included some screenshots that will hopefully help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am quite sure that an important part of your private key is recoverable.

Comment: please include the exact error messages when you post questions

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310313/problems-with-creation-of-database-dvwa